# How to install aprun in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cray

In this tutorial,

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFnewLG-y2E
CUDA Part C: The CUDA Toolkit: Libraries, Profilers, Debuggers
```

I found the presenter used a command `aprun`,after googling,I found it seem come from:Cray Linux Environment,question is how to install aprun in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It is about CUDA programming,why does somebody downvote this question without any comments?

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with CUDA programming, which is why I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aprun comes with the Cray software stack (part of the alps module) and you get it when you purchase a Cray.  There's not a generic linux installer for it for off-Cray use.